# Properly export text format and editor settings

Tags: 8, importing-exporting, wysiwyg, configuration, input-formats

I'm trying to export the CKeditor settings and restricted_html settings but it's partially imported in the end.
[image]

I'm exporting the `editor.editor.restricted_html.yml` and the `filter.format.restricted_html.yml` files but I'm not getting the correct settings for enabled filters upon installation, but I'm getting the styles dropdown config for example. This results in an empty styles dropdown in the editor for the end user.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue.  Were you able to find the solution?